# A shape that resembles a fractal

Tags: geometry, fractals

This shape is modified from Koch snowflake. This line is not smooth and jagged but has finite length unlike the Koch snowflake. I am wondering if there is a name for this kind of shapes. I can't find anything related from google.

The shape:

1. Take a line segment, divide the line segment into three segments of equal length.
2. Draw an isosceles triangle which the angle close to the initial line segment is $\frac\pi{3\cdot2^{k}}$that has the middle segment from step 1 as its base and points outward.
3. Remove the line segment that is the base of the triangle from step 2.

Repeat the above steps. Where $k$ in the number of iterations starting from $k=0$.

[image: modified koch snowflake]

The totoal length $\prod_{k=0}^\infty{\frac1 3} \left( {2+cot \left(\frac\pi{3\cdot2^{k}}\right)} \right)$ converges.

$$\prod_{k=0}^\infty{\frac1 3} \left( {2+cot\left(\frac\pi{3\cdot2^{k}}\right)} \right)$$
$$=exp\left[{\sum_{k=0}^\infty ln \left( {\frac2 3+\frac1 3cot\left(\frac\pi{3\cdot2^{k}}\right)} \right)} \right]$$
$$\le exp\left[{\sum_{k=0}^\infty ln \left( {\frac2 3+\frac1 3 + \frac1 3 \frac1 2{\left(\frac\pi{3\cdot2^{k}}\right)}^2 } \right)} \right]$$
$$\le exp\left[{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1 6{\left(\frac\pi{3\cdot2^{k}}\right)}^2 }  \right]$$
$$\le exp\left[\frac{\pi^2}{6\cdot9}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\frac1{2^{2k}}} }  \right]$$

edit:

I forgot to mentoin self-similarity. This shape is self-similar but in a distorted way. See graphs below, the ratio which x-axis and y-axis scales are different.
[image]

Comment: This is an iterated function system, which is a kind of fractal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system

Comment: Step 2 is not clear. Which angle is that? The one close to the initial line (two of them) or the vertex away from the original line?

Comment: @Andrei Yes. The angle is the one close to the initial line.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks. Though I was thinking about curves (2d shapes, 3d shapes) that have non-zero non-inifite length (area, volum) while also look like a fractal.

Comment: @anonymousRabbit there is no requirement that it have infinite length to be a fractal.

Comment: CyclotomicField All examples I know have inifite length. And I think fractal dimesion will be 1 if the length is finite.

Comment: This curve is *not* self-similar and *cannot* be generated by an iterated function system. I think that very few researchers in fractal geometry would think of this (or any rectifiable curve) as a fractal, though some might think of it as a *borderline fractal*, as described in [this paper](https://marksmath.org/scholarship/PLSystemsPP.pdf).

Comment: @CyclotomicField (because you were not pinged before) An iterated function system is a collection of functions, not a fractal.  Iterated functions systems are tools for *constructing* certain kinds of fractals.  Moreover, the set described in this question is not the attractor of an iterated function system, nor can it be constructed as the attractor of such a system.  I believe that the tool used here is an L-system (though I am less familiar with L-systems, so I don't want to stake my name to it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first directly address your question:

> I am wondering if there is a name for this kind of shape.

The answer is yes. Gerald Edgar calls these *borderline fractals* in his book *Measure, Topology, and Fractal Geometry*, as you can see in [this Google books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=dk2vruTv0_gC&q=borderline+fractal#v=snippet&q=borderline%20fractal&f=false).

I think it's worth pointing out that Mandelbrot himself famously defined a *fractal* to be a set whose Hausdorff dimension strictly exceeds its topological dimension. He later rescinded this definition, though, when he realized that there are curves with the "infinite crinkliness" we see in the Koch curve yet with Hausdorff dimension and topological dimension both equal to 1.

---

I also have a few comments on your construction. You're absolutely correct in saying that your curve is something like a self-similar shape but not quite. It certainly cannot be generated by an iterated function system.

Your curve can be described, however, using a common tool in the study of fractal geometry, namely a *parametric L-system*. I published [this paper](https://marksmath.org/scholarship/PLSystemsPP.pdf) on exactly that topic. I also just created [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/a2acf76568ab80f5) to make the code more widely available.

Since your curve has finite length, the coordinate functions are continuous with bounded variation. As such, they must be differentiable almost everywhere.

We can choose the scaling factor $r_k$ at the $k^{\text{th}}$ stage to go down to $1/4$ fast enough so that fractal dimension is 1 but slow enough so that the curve has infinite length. Perhaps, then, the resulting curve is more on the "fractal" side than the "borderline" side?

In the picture below, for example, the scaling factor at the $k^{\text{th}}$ step is

$$r_k = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5(k+1)}.$$

[image]

Comment: [+1] Very interesting.